# How can I push selected buttons name and value into javascript multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some buttongroups like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="RPPP">

            <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="1">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="2">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="3">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="4">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="5">5</button>
            </div>
```

...and at the bottom an "Analyse" button.

```
<a href="#last" id="secnext" class=" btn-lg btn-info " >Analyse</a>
```

[they look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UskUs.jpg)

In the eventlistener function i'd like to push the selected button's name and value into an multidimensional array.

```
 var myBtnn = document.getElementById('secnext');

        myBtnn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var array =[];

          //store buttons name and value both in an array

          }
```

So that I'll have them like:

[PPP][4]

[TTT][3]

[DDD][5]

Comment: How do other button groups look? Are other buttons in other groups?

Comment: should you use checkboxes?

Comment: @PankajShukla yes! Each of the buttongroups are in other groups, but they look the same.

Comment: @darham
should I?

Comment: imo yes! what you are doing in your js is adding an eventlistener to your analise button but your other buttons have no states to grab. unless you add eventlisteners to each of them and grab the value as the user clicks them you can't just call js to grab pushed buttons that have no changed state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample code.
You need `Array#reduce` and `forin` to achieve what you want.
Note that I am selecting all the buttons with this call:
Also, note that I have put all buttons in one group, but I hope you get the idea.

```
var coll = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

So, depending on your html you may want to change the html to select the buttons.

```js
var myBtnn = document.getElementById('secnext');

            myBtnn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                var array = [];
                var coll = document.querySelectorAll('button');
                //store buttons name and value both in an array
                var collArr = [].slice.call(coll);
                var ans = [];
                 
                var obj = collArr.reduce(function (obj, btn) {
                    if (!obj[btn.name]) {
                        obj[btn.name] = 0;
                    }
                    obj[btn.name]++;
                    return obj;
                }, {});

                for (var i in obj) {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                        ans.push([i, obj[i]]);
                    }
                }

                console.log(ans);
            });
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" id="RPPP">

        <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="1">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="2">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="3">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="PPP" value="4">4</button>
        

        <button type="button" class="btn" name="TTT" value="1">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="TTT" value="2">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="TTT" value="3">3</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn" name="DDD" value="4">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="DDD" value="5">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="DDD" value="4">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="DDD" value="5">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="DDD" value="5">8</button>
</div>
    
    <a href="#last" id="secnext" class=" btn-lg btn-info ">Analyse</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use objects instead of arrays.
So if you have an object like PPP you can put an array inside the object.

Example:

```
var obj = {
    'PPP' : ['1', '2'],
    'TTT' : ['1', '2']
};
obj.PPP[0] == '1';
obj.PPP[1] == '2';
obj.TTT[0] == '1';
obj.TTT[1] == '2';
```